# How can I get form a GameObject a list of components attached to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

components attached I mean by name of each component.

```
var list = gameObj.GetComponents(typeof(Component));
                if (!componentsList.Contains(gameObj.name))
                    componentsList.Add(gameObj.name);
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!componentsList.Contains(list[i].name))
                        componentsList.Add(list[i].name);
                }
```

This code create a List only with GameObjects.
But I want a List in this format for example:

Cube1
 Mesh Renderer
 Box Collider
Sphere
 Mesh Renderer
 Box Collider

In the end a List with each object name and the components of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume when you say you need the name of the component, you actually mean the type. Component.name actually returns the name of the GameObject the Component is attached to, so it will be the same for all components.

You could do the following

```
    foreach(var component in GetComponents()) {
        Debug.Log(component.GetType());
    }
```

I wonder what you will need that for though ...

Answer (score -1):

```
Component[] comps=gameObj.GetComponents();

List<Component> complist= new List<Component>();

for(inti =0;i<comps.length;i++){
complist.Add(comps[i]);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.